# How to read file names into an array in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor, I've got a meteor/public folder in my project with small thumbnail files in it.

```
jane_smith.jpg
bob_jackson.jpg
...
```

These are used for 'chips' in Materialize, small tags with the name and the image of the person.

The same meteor/public folder also has some first-initial images (letters A-Z) for those Materialize chips where there is no thumbnail image

```
initialA.png
initialB.png
...
```

What I'm trying to do is use the image file if it's available, or use the initial .png file if it's not. When the image is there it's no big deal.

```
{{#each List}}
<div class="chip">
     <img src="img/{{FullName}}.jpg">{{FullName}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Of course when the .jpg isn't there, the src reads no image. I'd like to somehow read the contents of meteor/public and put those names in an array so the .jpg file can be searched for. If it's not there, the appropriate (correct first letter) .png file would be used. Can this be done? Or is there some better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the file system on the server using the node "fs" module, documentation is here.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Be aware that the location of the public folder will be different in production, but you might be ok using a relative file path from your current working directory.

Are you adding these chips yourself at run time or are they static? Hopefully the latter, because otherwise meteor will rebuild when it detects a new file.

The other option is to read the chips into the database, and then you can look things up . vsivsi:file-collection is good for this (as are others)

Comment: For the thumbnails, as time goes on I'm able to get more images of the clients and add them manually to the project. I'll re-deploy the project every 1-2 weeks with the new set of images. I'll take a look at that module tonight.

Comment: Sounds like you are creating work for yourself. Allowing people to upload a photo is much better, I can give you some pointers if you are interested

Comment: The app is a private, in-house app used for a small company to keep track of clients. It's not a app for the clients to use. So, yeah, it's work sometimes.